# How to load some images from themoviedb on android using different movie id

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, themoviedb-api

i have problem with my thread code 
 
I want to load some images from TMDB where that has a different id, i'm using Asynctask to load the images
here my code :

```
void updateFavorite(){
    try{
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM favorit ORDER BY _id ASC", null);
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            String _id=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id_Movie"));
            request = new MovieDBAsyncTask();
            final String link = mv.URL+"/"+_id+"?&api_key="+mv.API_KEY;
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        request.execute(link).get(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                    } catch (TimeoutException | ExecutionException | InterruptedException | CancellationException e) {
                        request.cancel(true);
                        test = false;
                        if (conn != null)
                            conn.disconnect();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "different ID"? I have this used API before so I am presuming that you mean a different movie ID. If this is the case, what context do you need to load these images in?

Comment: yes, i mean a different movie ID. I am using AsyncTask to load these images

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use Picasso? In fact, the API returns links to load images so all you would have to do is put that link corresponding to the ID in a Picasso request. Nevertheless, if you don't want to use Picasso, I still don't quite understand where you're having issues. All you have to do is a new request with the link that corresponds to that ID.

Comment: yap, i'm using picasso too to get the pict, i set it on adapter class. I'm using asyncTask to get all of poster url then i call the image using picasso. The problem is about that asyncTask, i assume when i am repeating call tmdb url using AsyncTask with the different movie id will solve the problem, but it's not

Comment: Well the general calls, like "now_playing" are built without IDs like this `http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=key`. That'll return picture links like this, `http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/link`, which then you can load with Picasso. You only need the movie ID to request things like reviews & trailers. The ASyncTask call shouldn't happen more than once per type in the Main Activity.

Comment: ok i'll try first, thanks for the advice